# Coverage report for unit test

Tags: android, ant, junit, code-coverage, build.xml

I'm trying to get coverage report for my unit test, but BUILD always FAIL.

I'm using this tutorial ([blog.pboos](http://blog.pboos.ch/2011/06/coverage-fo-android-tests/comment-page-1/#comment-2512)) step-by-step.

Everything goes fine, except last step when i run ant coverage.

Here's what I get:

```
    D:\codecoverage\Regression>ant coverage
Buildfile: D:\codecoverage\Regression\build.xml
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 11
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.3.3
    [setup] API level: 10
    [setup]
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup]
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup]
    [setup]
    [setup] Importing rules file: tools\ant\test_rules.xml

-set-coverage-classpath:

-install-instrumented:
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 11
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.3.3
    [setup] API level: 10
    [setup]
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup]
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup]
    [setup]
    [setup] Importing rules file: tools\ant\main_rules.xml

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-set-debug-mode:

-pre-build:

-dirs:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

-aidl:
     [echo] Compiling aidl files into Java classes...

-renderscript:
     [echo] Compiling RenderScript files into Java classes and RenderScript byte
code...

-resource-src:
     [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...

-pre-compile:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\codecoverage\Regression\instrumented\c
lasses

-emma-instrument:
     [echo] Instrumenting classes from D:\codecoverage\Regression\instrumented/c
lasses...

-dex-instrumented:
     [echo] Converting compiled files and external libraries into D:\codecoverag
e\Regression\instrumented\classes.dex...
    [apply] SDK was unexpected at this time.

BUILD FAILED
D:\Programi\Android SDK Tools\tools\ant\test_rules.xml:63: The following error o
ccurred while executing this line:
D:\Programi\Android SDK Tools\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:688: The following error
occurred while executing this line:
D:\Programi\Android SDK Tools\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:203: apply returned: 255

Total time: 6 seconds
```

Any idea what's wrong? Could it be that I have spaces in Android SDK Tools folder?

Adding my build file of test project. Maybe it helps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyWalletActivityTest" default="help">

<!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
     tool.
     It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
     Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="local.properties" />

    <!-- The build.properties file can be created by you and is never touched
         by the 'android' tool. This is the place to change some of the
         default property values used by the Ant rules.
         Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

         source.dir
             The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
         out.dir
             The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

         Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
         be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

         -->
    <property file="build.properties" />

    <!-- The default.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
         tool, as well as ADT.
         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="default.properties" />


    <!-- Required pre-setup import -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/pre_setup.xml" />


<!-- extension targets. Uncomment the ones where you want to do custom work
     in between standard targets -->
<!--
    <target name="-pre-build">
    </target>
    <target name="-pre-compile">
    </target>

    [This is typically used for code obfuscation.
     Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
     If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir}]
    <target name="-post-compile">
    </target>
-->

    <!-- Execute the Android Setup task that will setup some properties
         specific to the target, and import the build rules files.

         The rules file is imported from
            <SDK>/tools/ant/
         Depending on the project type it can be either:
         - main_rules.xml
         - lib_rules.xml
         - test_rules.xml

         To customize existing targets, there are two options:
         - Customize only one target:
             - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
               <setup> task.
             - customize it to your needs.
         - Customize the whole script.
             - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
               into this file, *after* the <setup> task
             - disable the import of the rules by changing the setup task
               below to <setup import="false" />.
             - customize to your needs.
    -->
    <setup />

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ant was having trouble with sdk directory. Try to re-install android sdk in a path that does not contain any space (So never to "Program files" :) ).

You are getting that error "SDK was unexpected at this time." because most likely your android sdk path is like : .../blabla SDK/... (there is a space before SDK).

See here on: [code-gotcha-blogspot](http://code-gotcha.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-code-coverage.html)